# Copy from one workbook to another works on second run not first

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a sheet in one workbook to another workbook...

When I run it the first time I get Run-time error 1004 PasteSpecial method of range class failed...

if i run it again it works...

I am sure it is something to do with the active workbook or sheet but I cannot figure out what the issue is...

```
 Sub CopySupplierList()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim file_path As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim WS_FileLoc As Worksheet
    Dim wbname As String
    Dim WB_main As Workbook
    Dim WB_toUpdate As Workbook
    
    Set WB_main = ThisWorkbook
    Dim WS_active As String
    WS_active = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    If WS_active <> "TASK - Map and Validation" Then
    MsgBox "Please Close all other spreadsheets before running this process", 
    vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    GoTo ProcessEnd
    End If
    
    Set WS_FileLoc = Sheets("CONFIG - File Locations")
     ' Get work sheet
    Set wsf = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
   '=====================================================================================
   wbname = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
    file_path = WS_FileLoc.Range("B3").Value
    file_name = file_path & "/" & "Upload List.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=file_name
    Set WB_toUpdate = ActiveWorkbook
    
    WB_main.Activate
    wsf.Activate
    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
    Set wsf = Sheets("DATA - PriceList")
    
    wsf.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    wsf.Range("A1:u1").Select
   wsf.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
 
    WB_toUpdate.Close
    WB_main.Activate
    wst.Unprotect
    wst.Activate
    wst.Range("v6:ao6").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("a1").Activate
       wst.Range("v6:ao6").Interior.Color = 15773696
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    WB_toUpdate.Close
    ProcessEnd:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have `WB_toUpdate.Close` twice, are you making any changes to this workbook ? Also you have `Set wsf = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")` and later `Set wsf = Sheets("DATA - PriceList")`

Comment: Remove `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, `PasteSpecial` should not raise error. It's worth to read 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: No changes made to WB_toupdate - this is a sheet I am using to copy into the active sheet..  I copied  the close up after the select and must have missed deleting the 2nd one!

Comment: Thanks again - you all pointed me int the right direction...  does anyone have any guidelines or know where there is something that may help me structure my code better?

Comment: You are copying from `Sheets("DATA - PriceList")` in `WB_toUpdate` to `Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")` in `WB_main`. Is that correct ?

Comment: Thanks - This is working now - I can't see where I can close the question??

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes then I can probably "help you structure your code better"

Comment: yes...that would be helpful... i struggle with where to keep the dims sets etc so that it is easier to read..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySupplierList()
    
    Dim WS_FileLoc As Worksheet, arData, arHeader
    Dim WB_main As Workbook, WB_toUpdate As Workbook
    Dim wsf As Worksheet, wst As Worksheet
    Dim file_path As String, file_name As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    
    Set WB_main = ThisWorkbook
    With WB_main
        Set WS_FileLoc = .Sheets("CONFIG - File Locations")
        Set wst = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
    End With
    
    ' open workbook
    file_path = WS_FileLoc.Range("B3").Value
    file_name = file_path & "/" & "Upload List.xlsx"
    Set WB_toUpdate = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file_name)
    With WB_toUpdate.Sheets("DATA - PriceList")
        ' select ranges in source to arrays
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arHeader = .Range("A1").Resize(1, lastCol)
        arData = .Range("A2:U2").Resize(lastRow - 1, lastCol)
    End With
    WB_toUpdate.Close
   
    '  write array to table on target sheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wst
        If .ProtectContents Then .Unprotect
        Set tbl = .ListObjects(1) ' if 1 table otherwise use .ListObject("Table Name")
        ' size table for array
        With tbl
            ' clear existing data if any
            On Error Resume Next
            .HeaderRowRange.ClearContents
            .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' resize table and copy array to it
            .Resize .Range.Resize(UBound(arData) + 1, UBound(arData, 2)) ' +1 for header
            .HeaderRowRange = arHeader
            .HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, &HB0, &HF0)
            .DataBodyRange = arData
        End With
        .Protect
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Copy complete, rows = " & UBound(arData), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you really appreciate your help - i assume the array processing is a better way to do this type of thing

Comment: @craigcrowhurst Yes, for just copying values (not formats).

Comment: thanks again this has really helped me understand how to use Arrays...

Comment: i have just been testing this... works great apart from the destination V6:aO6 is a table called SPL_Table... how do i copy the array range into a table?

Comment: @craigcrowhurst Tables are a bit more difficult, copy header and data row separately - see update

Comment: thanks - that would explain it I tried copying all the data...  really appreciate all the help you have given

Comment: this is working great now thanks ..the last column of the WB_toupdate sheet can be variable so i want to make the array size dependent on the last column .. i tried the following bit it returns -1?  Set WB_toUpdate = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=file_name)
    WB_toUpdate.Activate
    Dim lastcol As Long
    lastcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
    With WB_toUpdate.Sheets(1)
        ' select ranges in source to arrays
           arHeader = .Range("A1:" & lastcol)
        arData = .Range("A2:" & lastcol & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

Comment: @craigcrowhurst `lastcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select` should be `lastcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column` but that gives a column number not a letter so `.Range("A2:" & lastcol & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` is not valid -see my update using `.Resize(n,m)` which uses numbers.